# SwiftUI / UIKit view where user can paste images

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, ios-stickers

Irrespective of the framework (SwiftUI/UIKit), what kind of view / UI element can I use that lets a user paste images, akin to what Instagram allows? In particular, I am interested about creating some kind of canvas where users can paste iOS 16 type stickers. How can I even approach this?

Specifically, I want to create an empty canvas that users can tap / long press and then a context menu opens where users can paste an image (or ios16 sticker)

Images to show what I mean / what Instagram has:

- Copying a sticker

[image]

- Instagram offers a Paste context menu

[image]

- The pasted sticker, can be freely moved around

[image]

Sorry for not posting any code etc, but I simply just need to know what kind of base view / approach to even use to attempt creating something like this.

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI, it seems like one way to do achieve this is by simply treating the stickers / images as `views`, and then make the views movable by attaching gestures

Minimal working example:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var scale: CGFloat = 1
    
    var magnificationGesture: some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged { scale in
                print("MagnificationGesture \(scale)")
                self.scale = scale
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(scale)")
            Spacer()
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .scaleEffect(self.scale)
                .gesture(
                    magnificationGesture
                )
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Now to add an image, simply replace the `Rectangle` by a `VStack` that also contains an image, you can get an image using `UIPasteboard.general.image`